# Count data from database on laravel

Tags: laravel, query-builder, laravel-5.7, laravel-controller

On php i could use this code to get how many item on my goods db

```
$total = 0;
$sql = "select count(*) as total from goods";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $total = $row['total'];
    }
}
echo $total;
// example return 5
```

can i do that on laravel? if i use this code on my controller

```
function show(Request $request){
    $c = DB::select("SELECT count(*) as total FROM goods");
    if($c > 0 ): a ? b;
}
```

it would get error message since it would return JSON inside array. Are there any better way to do this? Or how to get that total from $c inside controller

Answer (score 12, accepted):

used laravel [Aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#aggregates) methods  `count` method

```
$count = DB::table('goods')->count();

if($count > 0) {
     //more than one raw
}else {
     //zero raw
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `count()` function like this:

```
$count = DB::table('goods')->count();
```

You can also use Laravel Eloquent on **Good** model like this:

```
$count = Good::count();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = DB::table('goods')->count();
```

Please refer [link](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#aggregates)

Answer (score -2):

its much cleaner with eloquent

```
$c=goods::all()->count();
```

since the above will pull all collection and count, the more efficient way is

```
$c=goods::where('value',$val)->get()->count();
```

Comment: This will fetch all `goods` and count `collection`, not good, if there are millions of records.

Comment: i know its not a good practice but looking at his code, he is fetching all record